# PowerShell Wildcard Not Returning All Files

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and been trying to get this script to work.

```
If ((Get-Date -UFormat %a) -eq "Mon") {$intSubtract = -3} 
Else {$intSubtract = -1}
$datDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($intSubtract)

Write-Output "Find expected file --------------"
$strDate = ($datDate).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
Write-Host "strDate: $strDate"
$arrGetFile = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\Computer\Data\States\NorthDakota\Cities\*_Bismark_$strDate*.txt"

$strLocalFileName = $arrGetFile

If ($arrGetFile.count -ne 2)
{
Throw "No file or more than two files with today's date exists!"
}
Else {$strLocalFileName = $arrGetFile[0].Name}

Write-Output "Found file $strLocalFileName --------------"


#Encrypt each file 

foreach ($arrGetFile in $strPath)
{    
Write-Output "Start Encrypt --------------"
    $strPath = "\\Computer\Data\States\NorthDakota\Cities\"
    $FileAndPath = Join-Path $strPath $strLocalFileName
    $Recipient = "0xA49B4B5D"

    Import-Module \\JAMS\C$\PSM_PGP.psm1
    Get-Module Encrypt

    Encrypt $FileAndPath $Recipient
    $strLocalFileNamePGP = $strLocalFileName + ".pgp"

Write-Output "End Encrypt --------------"

        }
#Archive files 

Write-Output "Archiving --------------"

move-item -path \\Computer\Data\States\NorthDakota\Cities\*_Bismark_$strDate*.txt -destination \\Computer\Data\States\NorthDakota\Cities\Archive
```

The Cities folder will contain two files. Example 2015_Bismark_20150626_183121.txt and 2015_Bismark_20150626_183121_Control.txt

I am trying to get both files encrypted however it is only finding and encrypting the file without _Control. It is archiving both files correctly.
Not sure what I am missing to also find the control file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is incorrect.  You have `foreach ($arrGetFile in $strPath)`, but $strPath doesn't seem to contain anything at that point.

Your `for` loop should be:

```
foreach ($LocalFile in $arrGetFile)
```

And you need to remove the following line:

```
$strLocalFileName = $arrGetFile
```

This is making $strLocalFileName an array of file objects, but later in the script you are treating it like a string.  You may have more logical errors--you need to walk through the script very carefully and identify each variable and make sure it contains what you expect it to contain.

In general you seem to be treating arrays of non-string objects as if they are strings.  Note that I changed your `$strLocalFileName` variable to `$LocalFile`.  This is because it is a *file* object, not a *string* object.

Following is a sample that just shows that the `for` loop iterates through the both files.

```
If ((Get-Date -UFormat %a) -eq "Mon") {$intSubtract = -3} 
Else {$intSubtract = -1}
$datDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($intSubtract)

Write-Output "Find expected file --------------"
$strDate = ($datDate).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
Write-Host "strDate: $strDate"

$arrGetFile = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\Computer\Data\States\NorthDakota\Cities\*_Bismark_$strDate*.txt"

If ($arrGetFile.count -ne 2)
{
    Throw "No file or more than two files with today's date exists!"
}

Write-Output "Found files " ($arrGetFile | select Name | fl) "--------------"

#Process each file 
foreach ($LocalFile in $arrGetFile)
{    

    $FileAndPath = Join-Path $LocalFile.DirectoryName $LocalFile
    $FileAndPath

}
```

Start with this and then carefully add your encryption processing back into the loop.

Also, The line that assigns `$FileAndPath` could be removed.  You can just use `$LocalFile.FullName` wherever you need the full path and filename.